# Crystal Report Function for converting Seconds to Timespan format

Tags: function, crystal-reports, timespan

I have a crystal report where it shows the Agent's activities throughout the day with a pie chart. In the details section it is displaying:

- Activity [string]
- StartedAt [DateTime]
- EndedAt [DateTime]
- Duration [The difference between   EndedAt and  StartedAt in seconds -   Integer]

Report data is GroupedBy Activity and summarized by Duration.

Currently Duration is shown in seconds but I need to format it 02h:30m:22s:15ms. For that I wrote a custom function in Crystal Report in the Formula Workshop editor as follows, but it looks like the syntax is not right (Error message on keyword Long: "A variable type (for example, 'String') is missing."). Can someone help?

```
Function GetTimeSpanString(seconds as Long)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( seconds );
    GetTimeSpan = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms",  
                            ts.Hours,  
                            ts.Minutes,  
                            ts.Seconds,  
                            ts.Milliseconds) 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily alter my [ElapsedTime()](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/29/crystal-reports-elapsedtime-function/) function to meet your needs.